# ASP.Net Web API 404 error on production server

Tags: rest, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

We are facing an issue after deploying our asp.net web api to production server. 404 not found is occurring after every hit on the api. Following is already installed on production server.

1. .Net framework 4.6
2. ASP.Net MVC3

I have also tried multiple solutions found on different forums like register asp.net on iis and adding an entry in System.Webserver but nothing worked for us. Could someone help us to found the root cause of the issue?

Comment: Is your domain setup properly? Can you ping your server? Can you put a raw .txt file in the root and have it served? Your question doesn't give enough info to properly solve this issue. There are so many things that could be wrong and it doesn't appear to be .net related if everything is resulting in a 404.

Answer (score 1):

Please crosscheck this things:

- Have you enabled Cors policy.
- Are you typing proper Urls.
- Is hosted web site of IIS is in "Start" state.

Comment: Thanks Ravinda, Issue was related with the path. Actually we hosted the api on production on a subdomain that were making some wrong path thats why I am unable to hit. After making a separate domain and enablecors it works,